# Bootstrap 4 column system is not working for me

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have used this code but `col` is not working. It comes 1 below another. I tried checking same query but didn't find an answer.

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col col-lg-6">
    <h3>HOME</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
        <div class="col col-lg-6"><img src="imgs/tabs/left-1.png"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It will be side by side only in large and above viewports, did you check in medium resolution?

Comment: yes i have checked it on every device,, it is not working.

Comment: Can you post your full code. Or a link to the page

Comment: http://thesmokysnooker.com/pointmatrix/  this is the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the link to bootstrap. You can learn how to get started with bootstrap here: [Bootstrap Get started](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/)

Also you can learn about the different grid systems here: [Bootstrap Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/)

For now this code should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-lg-6">
            <h3>HOME</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
         </div>

         <div class="col col-lg-6"><img src="imgs/tabs/left-1.png"></div>
         </div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

In your provided website link the row class is not set to the parent div correctly.
Please change the class "col-lg-12" into "row" like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6"><img src="imgs/tabs/left-1.png" class="img-fluid"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: i have downloaded the bootstrap 4.0 file n have attached it to html pages... (bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap.min.js and https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js) these are three files i have connected

Comment: @MsDesigner Can you add your whole HTML Code please

Comment: @MsDesigner I edited my response. With this change your code will work. Please vote for my answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Col is working properly, you need to check your CDN for bootstrap.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

try below:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col col-lg-12">
            <div class="col col-lg-6">
            <h3>HOME</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-lg-6"><img src="imgs/tabs/left-1.png"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```